# Client validation broken due to NamingContainer ID using ASCX as MVC-View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, webforms

**The situation**

I'm currently migrating a WebForms application to MVC. Some old controls make heavy use of the WebForms form validation framework (the old validators, such as `RequiredFieldValidator`) and for the moment I am dependent on that specific behaviour.

It is far too costly to rewrite those controls entirely. But what I can do, is migrate them into `ASCX`-MVC-Views. That allows me to use the old validators and controls while using them via `Html.Partial` etc. in `cshtml`-files.

**The problem**

When I do that, I get various JS syntax errors in the generated validation code resulting from bad client IDs of the form controls:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var 1_ctl05 = document.all ? document.all["1_ctl05"] : document.getElementById("1_ctl05");
...
```

The problem here is, that variables may not start with a number (1). That number 1 is where the naming container will usually generate some prefix.

Upon inspection, I noticed that the ID of the ASCX-control is indeed "1", as is the `NamingContainer.ID` property of the validator and its parents.

Now, I can 'fix' this problem by implementing the `PageLoad`-Event, and setting `this.ID` to something starting with a character. But I get the feeling I'm either doing something wrong here (can I set the ID somewhere more properly?) or this is a bug.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though still not entirely sure why the naming container is empty, I noticed that the faulty (and nasty) global JavaScript code can be avoided entirely by using the jQuery unobtrusive validation.

So the "fix" would be using unobtrusive validation whenever working with MVC and ASCX/ASPX forms.